# Salesforce REST API create new access_token in every thread

Tags: java, salesforce

I have a Java client that connects to Salesforce to send data to Salesforce. I've recently found out that this client can be multithreaded. I'm using a simple username/password to get the access token.

```
    post = new PostMethod(environment);
    post.addParameter( "grant_type", "password" );
    post.addParameter( "username", username );
    post.addParameter( "password", password );
    post.addParameter( "client_id", clientId );
    post.addParameter( "client_secret", clientSecret );

    httpClient.executeMethod( post );
```

Is this going to be a problem if each thread gets its own token? Does the previous token expire if a new one is created? If so, what's the best way to handle the multiple connections?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer on some of your questions:

1. Usually Salesforce provides one token per one SF account (so, you should have username, password and token).
2. When you generate new token the old one expire.
3. As for multithreading connection - I'm not sure, SF allows or not to connect in parallel with one username/pass pair.